# How to change navigation bar color in outside of safe area

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

[image]

This view is **Present** from mainviewcontroller then i set large title on this view then then i change color of navigation bar but color is not change in outside of safe area in navigation bar.

so, how can i change color in whole navigation bar in iPhone X.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the view controller constructed from a storyboard? Please show how you have set up the constraints.

Comment: No its from xib and i do present with navigation controller, then safeArea navigation background color is properly changed upside area color is not change like above image.

Comment: If you use a navigation controller to present, it will extend the view up to top for you. Otherwise you need to extend up to top yourself. Is your xib extending to top or to safe area?